# Integral closure of 1-dimensional noetherian local domains

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $(R,m)$ be a $1$-dimensional noetherian local domain and $S$ its integral closure. Clearly $S$ is $1$-dimensional noetherian semi-local domain. Is $mS=J(S)$, where $J(S)$ is the
Jacobson radical of $S$?

Comment: I don't think so. Take $(R,m)=(p\Bbb Z^{(p)}, (p^2))$. The normalization of $(R,m)$ is $S=(\Bbb Z^{(p)},(p))$, but $m\Bbb Z^{(p)}=(p^2)\ne (p)=J(S)$

Comment: @AdamHughes What is $\mathbb Z^{(p)}$?

Comment: @AdamHughes: Is your counterexample a ring without 1?

Comment: @user26857 the $p$ local integers, i.e. $\{a/b: a,b\in\Bbb Z,\,\gcd (b,p)=1\}$

Comment: @zcn yes. Taken after the general orders in a number field, $k$, (i.e. integral ideals) and their integral closure/normalization $\mathcal{O}_k$. Since the op wanted a local version, I localized a specific example. Neukirch uses them as typical Nötherian domains of dimension $1$.

Comment: @AdamHughes: That ring is typically written $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$, as it is a localization of $\mathbb{Z}$ at the prime ideal $(p)$. Although what you point out is true, giving a ring without $1$ doesn't seem particularly relevant, especially when talking about domains

Comment: @zcn possibly, but I'm pretty confident that depends upon your personal context. In any case, it works for those who work with the CRing definition which does not require a $1$.

Answer (score 2):

One can use the following proposition to find a counterexample:

**Proposition:** Let $R$ be a Noetherian complete local domain. If $R \subseteq S \subseteq \text{Quot}(R)$ and $S$ is integral over $R$, then $S$ is local.

Proof: $R \subseteq S$ is module-finite (since under the assumptions, the integral closure $\overline{R}$ is module-finite over $R$, see e.g. Swanson-Huneke, Theorem 4.3.4). The result then follows e.g. from Corollary 7.6 in Eisenbud.

Thus, it suffices to give an example of a $1$-dim Noetherian complete local domain $(R,m)$ such that for $S = \overline{R}^{\text{Quot}(R)}$, $mS$ is not a prime ideal. One such ring is $R = k[[t^3,t^4,t^5]]$. Then $S = k[[t]]$, and $mS = (t^3,t^4,t^5)S \ne tS = J(S)$.

Comment: The proposition really holds for an integral extension? I've tried to use Nagata's theorem (about the integral closure of a noetherian complete local domain in a finite field extension of its field of fractions) to prove it, and I think I need $R\subset S$ finite. On the other side, you don't need the proposition in all its generality; in fact, you use Nagata's theorem

Comment: @user26857: I did not think too much about proving it, but from what I recall, this is true. As you say though, this does not affect the example at hand, which is a finite extension

Comment: @user26857: After amending to make a slightly more modest statement, I have added a proof (by reference)